# file_get_contents with a encoded url

Tags: php

I am having some trouble with a url I encoded, I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.

> Warning: file_get_contents(%27http%3A%2F%2Fapi.steampowered.com%2FISteamUser%2FGetPlayerSummaries%2Fv0002%2F%3Fkey%3D%27+..+%27%26steamids%3D%27+..) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Is it not looking outside my home directory?  Anyone know how to make the url function?

Any help would be awesome!

```
<?php

$url= "'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' .$apikey. '&steamids=' .$keyword.";
$string=file_get_contents(urlencode($url));

$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

$json_o=json_decode($string);
//array method
foreach($json_a[personaname] as $p)
{
echo '
<p>
Name: '.$p[response][players][personaname].'

';

}

?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `"` and `'` in `$url`. Please fix it and all will be fine. Also there's no need to use `urlencode`.

Comment: Also, remove the `urlencode` when using `file_get_contents`. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your URL enclosed in only one type of quotes:

```
$url= "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $apikey .  '&steamids=' . $keyword;
```